# Sorting columns in dataframes with panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I’m completely new to python so I don’t have a clue where to start but I have an excel spreadsheet table with 10,000 pieces of data about the google App Store. I’ve imported panda and imported the csv into python aswell. There are 5 columns including name, genre, rating, price, downloads. I need to sort the data frame from highest price first and descending down. Anyone have any simple solutions?

Comment: [explained very well](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('google-play-store.csv')
df.sort_values(by=['price'], ascending=False)
```

Comment: you need to use either inplace=True or store returned df into a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a very good API documentation for pandas. You can explore the sort_values method for a DataFrame [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

Note, by default it places NA values at the last, sorts in ascending order and inplace = False (that is return a new df). For your problem, you can use

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_filename.csv')
df.sort_values(by='price', ascending=False, inplace=True)
```